# MVC application class

Tags: php, object-oriented, mvc, url-routing

Please could you review and critic my code and logic? Is this is along the right lines of an MVC application class or not?

```
namespace dh_mvc2;

    use dh_mvc2\dispatchers\Base_Dispatcher;
    use dh_mvc2\routers\Base_Router;
    use dh_mvc2\autoloaders\Basic_Autoloader;
    use dh_mvc2\classes\Config;

    class Application {
    protected $_config;
    protected $_autoloader;
    protected $_app_path;
    protected $_framework_path;
    protected $_router;
    protected $_dispatcher;

    /**
     *
     * @param string $app_path
     *          "path/to/application/directory";
     * @throws \DH_MVC2_Application_Exeption
     */
    public function __construct($app_path, $run = TRUE) {
        if (! is_dir ( $app_path )) {
            require_once 'exeptions/DH_MVC2_Application_Exeption.php';
            throw new \DH_MVC2_Application_Exeption ( "Must supply a path to an application directory" );
        }

        $this->_framework_path = realpath ( dirname ( __DIR__ ) );
        $this->_app_path = $app_path;
        $this->set_ini_default_paths ();
        $this->init ();

        if ($run) {
            $this->run ();
        }
    }

    /**
     * add the framework dir and application dir to include path
     */
    private function set_ini_default_paths() {
        $paths = explode ( PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path () );
        if (array_search ( $this->_app_path, $paths ) === false) {
            array_push ( $paths, $this->_app_path );
        }
        if (array_search ( $this->_framework_path, $paths ) === false) {
            array_push ( $paths, $this->_framework_path );
        }
        set_include_path ( implode ( PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths ) );
        spl_autoload_register ();
    }

    /**
     * links to the app and framework default config files and inits them
     * registers autoloader
     */
    private function init() {
        $config_file = '/config/config.ini.php';
        $config_files ['DH_MVC'] = __DIR__ . $config_file; //framework config
        $config_files ['APP'] = $this->_app_path . $config_file; //app config

        $this->_config = new Config ( $config_files );
        $config_paths = $this->_config->get_paths ();
        $this->_autoloader = new Basic_Autoloader ( $config_paths );
    }

    /**
     * creates new base router instance which reads the url request and routes
     * application onto Action Controllers
     */
    public function run() {
        $this->_router = new Base_router ( $this->_config );
        $route = $this->_router->run ();

        if ($route) {
            $this->_dispatcher = new Base_Dispatcher ( $route );
            $this->_dispatcher->run ();
        }
    }
}
```

Not moved the initialization of new router to construct in order to remove protected `$_config` as I might use this attribute depending on how I develop the class. If not used I will remove.

```
$config_files ['DH_MVC'] = __DIR__ . $config_file;
```

It uses `__DIR__` as `$_framework_path` is parent of **DIR**.  $_framework_path takes into account my namespace dh_mvc2 thats used as the first directory, by the spl_autoload, from the framework basepath

```
namespace dh_mvc2\application;

    use dh_mvc2\classes\Config;
    use dh_mvc2\dispatchers\Base_Dispatcher;
    use dh_mvc2\routers\Base_Router;
    use dh_mvc2\autoloaders\Basic_Autoloader;

    class Application {
    protected $_config;
    protected $_autoloader;
    protected $_app_path;
    protected $_framework_path;
    protected $_router;
    protected $_dispatcher;

    /**
     *
     * @param string $app_path
     *          "path/to/application/directory";
     * @throws \DH_MVC2_Application_Exeption
     */
    public function __construct($app_path, $run = TRUE) {
        if (! is_dir ( $app_path )) {
            require_once 'exeptions/DH_MVC2_Application_Exeption.php';
            throw new \DH_MVC2_Application_Exeption ( "Must supply a path to an application directory" );
        }

        $this->_framework_path = realpath ( dirname ( __DIR__ ) );
        $this->_app_path = $app_path;
        $this->set_ini_default_paths ();
        $this->init ();
        $d = new Config ();
        if ($run) {
            $this->run ();
        }
    }

    /**
     * add the framework dir and application dir to include path
     */
    private function set_ini_default_paths() {
        spl_autoload_register ();
        $paths = explode ( PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path () );
        array_push ( $paths, $this->_app_path );
        array_push ( $paths, $this->_framework_path );
        $paths = array_unique ( $paths );
        set_include_path ( implode ( PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths ) );
    }

    /**
     * links to the app and framework default config files and inits them
     * registers autoloader
     */
    private function init() {
        $config_file = '/config/config.ini.php';
        $config_files ['DH_MVC'] = __DIR__ . $config_file; // framework config
        $config_files ['APP'] = $this->_app_path . $config_file; // app config
        $this->_config = new Config ( $config_files );
        $config_paths = $this->_config->get_paths ();
        $this->_autoloader = new Basic_Autoloader ( $config_paths );
    }

    /**
     * creates new base router instance which reads the url request and routes
     * application onto Action Controllers
     */
    public function run() {
        $this->_router = new Base_router ( $this->_config );
        $route = $this->_router->run ();

        if ($route) {
            $this->_dispatcher = new Base_Dispatcher ( $route );
            $this->_dispatcher->run ();
        } else {
            require_once 'exeptions/DH_MVC2_Router_Exeption.php';
            throw new \DH_MVC2_Router_Exeption ( "Failed to discover route" );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks pretty good to me.

Some thoughts for entertainment;

- If you created the router in init(), then _config would not be required any more as a protected property, one less private property
- There seems to be no error handling when `$this->_router->run ()` fails.
- `set_ini_default_paths` violates DRY, but only once, have you considered just adding the paths and then calling `array_unique`. Not sure that is the right way to go, but it could be considered.
- _autoloader is nowhere used, and it is private. Seems pointless?
- Should `$config_files ['DH_MVC'] = __DIR__ . $config_file;` not use `$this->_framework_path` ?

Comment: Thanks Tom.  The autoloader class registers an spl_autoload_register callback function that uses the conifg paths passed to its constructor. The call back function is one of the autoloaders own methods. Hopefully allowing me to inherit and override the autoload callback for other 'types' of autoloaders. If that all made sense?

Comment: your other points will be implemented now though. Well after looking at that array function to try fix the DRY issue

Answer (score 1):

I have some criticism on details you didn't ask, but which should be addressed:

#### Autoloading

Make use of it! There is no need to make manual calls to `require_once()`.

There even is a standard: [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), which defines how you should structure your class and namespace names together with the directory and file structure. When I look at your code, I see some issues: Because the underscore was used as a separator before PHP got namespaces, it is considered a separation character in class names.

#### Namespaces

Make use of it! I cannot see a reason why the exception \DH_MVC2_Application_Exeption is located in the root namespace, and not called \dh_mvc2\application\Exception. It would be so much easier to simply `throw new Exception();` inside the "\dh_mvc2\application" namespace.

#### Whitespace and coding style

Endless debates might occur, but I really don't like yours. Especially the inconsistent placement of parentheses. Personally, I'd rather prefer not to use that much spaces, but if you really have to, use them everywhere. For example, if you want to find the function "set_ini_default_paths", and want to make sure not to find "set_ini_default_paths_directory", you'd search for "set_ini_default_paths(" - which will find only function definitions, but not usage. To find these, you'd have to search "set_ini_default_paths (".

#### Dependency injection

Doesn't take place. Objects are created inside your class. There is no way I would be able to change for example the Config object if I'd use your class, I must use yours. I even cannot change the config filename!

#### Include path

Be careful what you add here. If a PSR-0 autoloader is used, there is no need to add anything to the include path. In fact, you'll get a good amount of performance if you include as few directories as possible, preferably only ".", to be able to include files with a relative path.

Comment: Thanks Sven. I'm kind of confused with the DI thing people keep mentioning.

Comment: Zend framework for example (ignoring the code) needs its config and application configs defined a certain way right? ok admittedly you can define the config zend uses in one of several ways but still define to their framework standard? And also i may be mistaken but Zend also requires the config to be in a set place within dir structure and without checking, named to a set convention also?

Comment: Your comments about Namespaces and auto-loading though I understand. And currently trying to get both to work correctly without require/includes. My class would still be called   DH_MVC2_Application_Exeption but located in the dir dh_mvc2\application\Exception right?

Comment: Looking at zend again, with respect to configs. You can specify the path to config file, and can have one of several formats. So maybe i should allow for my config to be located anywhere. But i'm still confused as to why requiring-'coupling' my application class to use a 'known' config (and autoloader) is wrong. Am i missing something big here? Or could i write a config file/autoloader how i wanted and throw it at zend and other frameworks and they would happily use them?

Comment: I think i figured out why I was struggling with auto-loading thanks to your link to the PSR-0.  DH_MVC2_Application_Exception would work if my directory was DH/MVC2/Application/Exception but my root dir was DH_MVC2 which auto-loader resolves as DH/MVC2 (if i understand it right?). Thank you for that

Comment: Have a look at the code of "public/index.php" [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.quick-start.html) and realize that the full path to the application.ini file is passed to the Zend_Application object. This file can be located anywhere (I'd be able to pass "/etc/zend/global_app_config.ini" if I want to), and only because of convention it is usually located in "config/application.ini".

Comment: And please do not look too closely at Zend Framework version 1. PHP and technology have improved dramatically since it's creation, and some examples used in this old version should rather be considered harmful today.

Comment: This might well be where I'm going very wrong!! My zend studio version is old and I've been avoiding ZF2 simply because the thought of setting it up with the IDE scares me! But I think you may have figured out why I'm struggling. trying to mix new 'thoughts' while trying to mimic an old frameworks methodology... So bye bye ZF1 (if i can get 2 up and running!)